# Starbound - Smasher or Poker

Tags: starbound

If you craft an anvil you unlock some weapons, the most powerfull ones are the "poker"(a spear) and the "smasher"(a warhammer), they have the same attack power, and the poker has a better swing speed, but the smasher needs 20 iron while the poker needs 10, is it because the smasher is better in any way or is it for no reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Weapons are all up to preference.

I've found that swing speed doesn't matter much as timing your attacks is more helpful than just spamming attacks.As for the spear vs. warhammer, the warhammer would be easier to hit with since it does an overhead swing, whereas the spear does a forward thrust.

Another thing to look at when comparing weapons is armor penetration, as that seems to be more important than straight damage.

Comment: both of them have 5 armor penetration, but i'm gonna make the warhammer, it looks cooler